# How to exactly sign AWS elasticsearch search request in axios using Nodejs if I am not using cognito?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

**Purpose of web app:** User visits site, inputs their data and selects the store they are responsible for and hits submit. Then in back end dynamoDB will connect the two sets of data - user contact to store info. I am using api gateway to hit the search and create routes - no authentication involved, besides iam role which allows lambda to talk to ES and dynamoDB.

1) I am not using Cognito or authenticating - I don't need it for this use case, this is for a survey app. However, I am using Elasticsearch to help with my autocomplete drop down/search fields.

2) I am able to make a normal non signed axios call to get search results (see code (A1) below). Params.url has the {endpoint}/indexname/_search. This works because right now I have my endpoint wide open.

**What I want to accomplish:** I want to lock down my ES domain so it is a bit more secure. While IAM role allows my lambda to talk to ES, unless ES is wide open I can't do the search functionality shown in (A1). I KNOW I have to sign my requests, but I am a little confused as to how to accomplish this using packages like aws4. The example shown on AWS site is a little confusing and I have not had any luck replicating it.

I have started the process with aws4 (seen in A2) but I am unclear how to get this working. Can someone please give some guidance? 
To summarize..: a) How do I implement the signed request with aws4 or any other method and b) what should the policy for the ES domain look like?

A1)

```js
axios({
    method: "post",
    url: params.url,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    data: {
      query: {
        query_string: {
          default_field: "Building Description",
          query: params.data
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

A2)

```js
axios(aws4.sign({
    host: process.env.ES_ENDPOINT,
    method: "POST",
    url: `https://${process.env.ES_ENDPOINT}/indexname/_search`,
    path: "/indexname/_search",
}))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is just use the AWS JavaScript SDK to do the signing and provide it with limited scope credentials.

**NB**: This does not mean using the AWS SDK ElasticSearch client.

When using the AWS SDKs in Lambda, this is done for you, but it can also be done in any javascript environment. Although I would think very carefully about using it client side, even that can have its uses.

Possible ways to add credentials for JavaScript SDK can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-credentials-node.html).

Example of making a signed request to ES using AWS JavaScript SDK can be seen [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-request-signing.html#es-request-signing-node).

There are several examples of resource based access policies [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-ac.html#es-ac-types-resource). I think what you are after will be in the bottom half of that page.

Comment: Yes! i got it, for whatever reason I missed the loading credentials. Now if may add on to my question: How can I incorporate axios with the signer.addAuthorization?

Comment: My understanding is that you should just be able to run axios(request) once you have run the addAuthorization method on your request. All it's doing is creating the signature. Admittedly, I haven't tried this.

Comment: I figured it out, you can use third party library aws4 to sign the request using accesskeyid and secretkey of user you create on IAM. You will have to add this user   as the principal in the domain policy for ES. Then it will be secure. Just give the user ability to do a get/post only, that way its locked down. Also keep the access key securely in lambda either encrypted or use ssm. Your initial answer let me in the right direction so marking it correct in case anyone sees this.

Answer (score 0):

the [aws4-axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws4-axios) lib makes this very easy now.